# How to integrate Mailgun with email-templates?

Tags: javascript, mailgun, nodemailer, email-templates

Using [Email-Templates](https://github.com/niftylettuce/email-templates)(templating library)
with [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/).

Problem is I don't know how to send that template in an email via Mailgun.

**My Research:**

1. What I found in the documentation is we need to update the transport object which we see in the image below

[image]
2. There are some examples which shows examples to change transport in the following ways:

***One way***

```
{
  "transport": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 25,
    "secure": false,
    "tls": {
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  }
}
```

***Another way***

```
// EmailService.js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const mailgunTransport = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport')
// Configure transport options
const mailgunOptions = {
  auth: {
    api_key: process.env.MAILGUN_ACTIVE_API_KEY,
    domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN,
  }
}
const transport = mailgunTransport(mailgunOptions)
```

My question is: How to use them together?

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a transporter with `createTransporter` and pass it into `transport`.

> Use **`smtp`** credentials in `user`and `pass`

You can find the `smtp` credentials in `Domain Settings` of Mailgun.

```
const Email = require('email-templates');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
    service:  'Mailgun',
    auth: {
     user: '<SMTP>.mailgun.org',
     pass: '<PASSCODE>'   
    }
});


const email = new Email({
  message: {
    from: 'user@email.com'
  },
  // uncomment below to send emails in development/test env:
  send: true,
  transport: transporter
});
```